# Running 32-bit dll on 64-bit machine in java

Tags: java, dll, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am attempting to use a 3rd-party dll for a program I am writing in java. Unfortunately, it only has 32-bit support. When I attempt to load the dll in a 64-bit VM, I get the following error:

```
Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

I have tried running in a 32-bit VM, which works in eclipse, but when I export the project, I get the same error. Please help!

Sincerely, Ben

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the right java outside of Eclipse? Try a java -version to check if the right one (32bit) is used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot use a 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit Hotspot JVM.  It won't work.  And I don't know of any other 64-bit JVM that supports 32-bit DLLs.

Indeed, as Peter Lawrey points out, this is not just a JVM limitation.   No mainstream operating system allows an application running in 64-bit mode to load and use a 32-bit library.

Your choices are:

- Switch to a 32-bit JVM.  (You *can* run a 32bit JVM on a 64-bit OS ...)
- Port the DLL to 64-bit.
- Switch to an alternative library that is pure Java, or has a 64-bit DLL.

---

> I have tried running in a 32-bit VM, which works in eclipse, but when I export the project, I get the same error.

That can only mean that you are running a 32-bit JVM to run the application within Eclipse, and a 64-bit JVM to run the application outside of Eclipse.  (The issue is how you run the application, not how you export it ...)

Comment: +1 I don't know of any OS which allows 64-bit applications to load 32-bit shared libraries. Its not a limitation of Java.

Comment: I found this question and answer, after a long long string of searches, on why my code failed. This solved it. Thanks a million. I learned something today!

Answer (score 4):

The only way to use a 32-bit shared library from a 64-bit JVM is to run an additional 32-bit JVM and access it via RMI, JMS or some form of messaging.

Its an intrinsic limitation of 64-bit programs (not just Java) that it cannot exchange pointers with a 32-bit library.